# ANDROID STUDIO Persistent wifi scanner

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a wifi scanner project on an Android API 19

My problem is when the screen is off, after about 10 minutes it stops scanning the wifi
and when I turn on my device the scan starts again correctly.

I can not remove deep sleep :/

how to do a persistent wifi scan properly ??

someone has a suggestion ??

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's a normal behaviour for android phones to close apps after x minutes of screen off. You need to create a service wich can scan your wifi even in background or closed state.

Answer (score 0):

I am root on my device, this is my service background scan wifi

AndroidManifest :

```java
     <service android:name=".wifi" android:process=":my_service" android:enabled="true"  android:priority="999"  android:exported="true"  android:label="Preferences"/>
```

service WIFI

```java
class scanner_wifi extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public void onCreate() {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        final WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(mWifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Log.e("WIFI_SCAN","NEW SCAN WIFI");
                    tts.speak("WIFI", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();


                    final int N = results.size();

                    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "  BSSID       =" + results.get(i).BSSID);
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "  SSID        =" + results.get(i).SSID);
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "  Capabilities=" + results.get(i).capabilities);
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "  Frequency   =" + results.get(i).frequency);
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "  Level       =" + results.get(i).level);
                        Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "---------------");


                    }
                }
            }, filter);
            mWifiManager.startScan();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "This Language is not supported");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("WIFI_SCAN", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

my code works well but after x minutes of screen off , the device close my apps :/

Thanks for your help